# Align image in unordered list with list items

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a menu consisting of an unordered list with multiple list items where they all contain text except the last one, that one contains an image. the problem is that I want to align the center of the image with the center of the text in the other list items but I can't figure out how to do it.
Tried different thing with the margin, padding and height but can't seem to figure it out

Here's a **[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e1sxysbq/)**

HTML

```
<div class="menu-main-container">
    <ul id="menu-main" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-1"> <a href=#>Item1</a>

        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-2"> <a href=#>Item2</a>

        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-3"> <a href=#>Item3</a>

        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-4"> <a href=#><img src="http://www.goldcoastjazz.org/images/buttons_icons/More-Details-121x30_copy.jpg"/></a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menu-main-container ul {
    text-align : left;
    display : inline;
    list-style : none;
    text-transform : capitalize;
    text-decoration : none;
    padding : 0;
    margin : 0;
}
.menu-main-container ul li a {
    text-transform : capitalize;
    text-decoration : none;
    color : #000000;
    font-weight : bold;
}
.menu-main-container ul li {
    display : inline;
    position : relative;
    cursor : pointer;
    padding : 25px;
}
.menu-main-container ul li:hover {
    background-color : #003cb3;
}
.menu-main-container ul li:hover > a {
    color : #fff;
}
li#menu-item-4:hover {
    background-color: white;
}
li#menu-item-4 {
}
li#menu-item-4 a {
}
li#menu-item-4 a img {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `vertical-align: middle` get working, you must specify a line-height:

```css
li#menu-item-4 a {
    line-height: 30px;
}
li#menu-item-4 a img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

See [this update fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/e1sxysbq/7/).

Comment: But then I get the problem that I raised before: It moves all the elements upwards a bit and the list as a whole isn't vertically aligned properly. Or that just a matter of changing the line-height?

Comment: No, the line-height has to be the same as the image's height. Adjust the padding, and everything is just fine.

Comment: but if you look at your fiddle you can see the padding is over the boundary if i set it to something like 25px (what the client wants)

Comment: Mistake. Yes, adjust the line-height. But you'll have some trial-and-error to do to get it right. See [your original](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/e1sxysbq/11/), [something you can work with I think](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/e1sxysbq/10/), and a [strange alternative](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/e1sxysbq/9/).

Answer (score 1):

**[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/e1sxysbq/1/)**

use `vertical-align: middle;`

Note: You can only use vertical-align on elements that act like a table. Therefor you need to change `display: table` on parent and `display: table-cell` on the content + `vertical-align: middle;`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
li#menu-item-4 a img {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
}

.menu-main-container ul li {
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    /* other styles */
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e1sxysbq/4/)**

Comment: That does align it properly, but then all of the list items go upwards a bit and they are no longer vertically aligned correctly (see http://jsfiddle.net/e1sxysbq/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `vertical-align: middle` on your image. See a fork of your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/58roatpd/1/