# Menu CSS not working properly in IE11

Tags: html, css

Quick Note: I can't actually look if the answers given can help me until next monday unfortunately

I have a menu with some submenu's (2 levels deep) and have all the CSS working in Chrome but it doesn't show properly in IE11. Whats even weirder is that the same menu completely screws up when it's viewed from my local test server and works (almost) fine when viewed on the remote server.
The problem lies in the sub menu. when hovering the top level the sub menu should be displayed beneath the top level but in IE it is displayed over the top level. You can see the example at http://dev.votob.nl (view in Chrome/Firefox for the desired result).

How can i fix the positioning in IE11?

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qg4p2smo/2/)

HTML:

```
<div class="menu-main-container">
    <ul id="menu-main" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-1"> <a href=#>Item1</a>

        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-2"> <a href=#>Item2</a>

            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-5"> <a href="#">Sub Item 1</a>

                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-6"> <a href="#">Sub Item 2</a>

                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-7"> <a href="#">Sub Item 3</a>

                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-8"> <a href="#">Sub Sub Item 1</a>

                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-9"> <a href="#">Sub Sub Item 2</a>

                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-10"> <a href="#">Sub Sub Item 3</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-3"> <a href=#>Item3</a>

        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-4"> <a href=#>Item4</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/*top level*/
 .menu-main-container > ul {
    text-align : left;
    display : table;
    list-style : none;
    text-transform : capitalize;
    text-decoration : none;
    padding : 0;
    margin : 0;
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
}
.menu-main-container ul > li {
    text-align : left;
}
.menu-main-container > ul > li {
    width: auto;
    display : table-cell;
    position : relative;
    cursor : pointer;
    vertical-align : middle;
    text-align : center;
}
.menu-main-container ul li a {
    text-transform : capitalize;
    text-decoration : none;
    color : #000000;
    font-weight : bold;
    font-size : 16px;
}
/*sub menu level 1*/
 .menu-main-container > ul > li:hover {
    background-color : #003cb3;
}
.menu-main-container > ul > li:hover > a {
    color : #fff;
}
.menu-main-container > ul > li > ul {
    position : absolute;
    top : 100%;
    width : 565px;
    display : none;
    opacity : 0;
    visibility : hidden;
    background-color : #FFFFFF;
    padding : 25px 25px 0px 25px;
}
.menu-main-container > ul > li > ul > li {
    display : block;
    color : #000000;
    width : 50%;
    list-style-type : none;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.menu-main-container > ul > li > ul > li > a {
}
.menu-main-container > ul > li > ul > li:hover > a {
    color : #003399;
}
.menu-main-container > ul > li:hover > ul {
    display : block;
    opacity : 1;
    visibility : visible;
}
/*sub menu positionering*/
 .menu-item-256 > ul.sub-menu {
    left : -299px;
}
/*sub menu level 2*/
 .menu-main-container > ul > li:hover > ul > li > ul {
    padding : 25px 25px 0px 25px;
    ;
    position : absolute;
    top : 0;
    width : 42%;
    left : 50%;
    margin-left: 0;
    display : none;
    opacity : 0;
    visibility : hidden;
}
.menu-main-container > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li {
    list-style-type : none;
}
.menu-main-container > ul > li:hover > ul > li > ul > li {
    border : none;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-right : 0;
}
.menu-main-container > ul > li:hover > ul > li:hover > ul {
    display : block;
    opacity : 1;
    visibility : visible;
}
.menu-main-container > ul > li:hover > ul > li > ul > li > a {
    color : #000000;
}
.menu-main-container > ul > li:hover > ul > li > ul > li:hover > a {
    color : #003399;
}
```

Comment: Please provide sample code here, as link references may break and hence become useless/make the question void

Comment: @jbutler483 The weird thing is I can't recreate the problem in a Fiddle, but ill post the code anyway

Comment: setting `.submenu { top: 60px }` or similar won't work?

Comment: @sb9 I already have a `top: 100%;` and that works fine in Chrome. Maybe I should mention that the menu is 'responsive' to a certain extent (it means it needs to resize dependong on the screen size till its no longer wanted and a 'mobile' menu pops up as you can see when you resize your window if you go to the dev.votob.nl link)

Comment: Using CSS hover states in this situation can get a little messy.. I would try using javascript to do this instead, like this http://jsfiddle.net/qd1yw5fh/. I don't think this qualifies as an answer, but I hope you find it helpful!

Comment: @ScottRowell that only toggles it right? Problem is it's for a client and the client wants hover...

Comment: Well, it toggles on hover. But if they're looking to specifically use CSS.. that's a bummer.

Comment: @ScottRowel if it toggles on hover it's fine, shall try it when I have the oppurtunity. Its that the only thing ill have to do? Or will it change the look in Chrome/Firefox as well?

Comment: To my knowledge, my solution should work across chrome, firefox, and IE. ..Give it a test though! As an extra bonus, you're able to add as many levels as you want to that without modifying css/javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe IE cannot handle the display: table(-cell) styles. Try to display it with ordinary (inline-)block styles:

```css
#menu {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 0;
    position: relative;
}
#menu * {
    font-size: 16px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#menu a {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
}
#menu > li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
}
#menu > li ul {
    text-align: left;
}
#menu > li:hover {
    background: #003cb3;
}
#menu > li:hover > a {
    color: #fff;
}
#menu > li > ul {
    background: #fff;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 25px 25px 0 25px;
}
#menu > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#menu > li > ul > li {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    width: 50%;
}
#menu ul li:hover > a {
    color: #039;
}
#menu > li > ul > li > ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 25px 25px 0 25px;
}
#menu > li > ul > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#menu > li > ul > li > ul > li {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">sub item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub item 3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">sub sub item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">sub sub item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">sub sub item 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">login</a></li>
</ul>
<p>Next element</p>
```

Comment: I need the table styles because of the vertical alignment of the elements (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27104801/align-image-in-unordered-list-with-list-items)

Comment: can you make that fiddle work with a 120x30 image? even though it's not the right question

Comment: Note that I display all anchors as block elements (in order to eliminate the need for the misleading cursor setting) and that could give a difference in the alignment too.

Comment: Noted, will check both solutions next week when I have the time

Comment: Finally had the chance of trying your solution, worked with the little addition of `float:left` in `#menu > li` otherwise the `li` elements wouldn't align horizontally in IE

Answer (score 0):

Move `position : relative` from `.menu-main-container > ul > li` to `.menu-main-container > ul`.

Then you can remove the `top : 100%` style.